# ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html-unsafe is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all I am using angular.1.3.0. Then I have,

```
<td class="vcenter" >{{data.videos}}</td>
```

It works but it encodes the html. Then I tried,

```
<td class="vcenter" ng-bind-html="data.videos"></td>
```

But It showed nothing. Then I tried,

```
<td class="vcenter" ng-bind-html-unsafe="data.videos"></td>
```

It also shows nothing. What I am missing?

Comment: Have you included `ngSanitize` in your module?

Comment: @devqon, included getting error that module not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/b9qtj56p/6/

Download file - angular-sanitize.js and include it in your app.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);       

app.controller('myController', function($scope,$compile) {
    $scope.html = '<p>Your html code</p>';
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="myController">
     <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have included this getting error that module not found

Comment: Download file - angular-sanitize.js and include it in your app.